# SignalR hub resolves to null inside RabbitMQ subscription handler in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, signalr, easynetq

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project with RabbitMQ (by means of EasyNetQ) and SignalR.

Next, I have a subscription on a RabbitMQ message that should send a notification to the client via SignalR.

But sadly, the hub always resolves to `null`.

An interesting observation is that when the application is still starting and there are still unacknowledged messages in the queue, the service actually resolves just fine.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.RegisterEasyNetQ("host=localhost;virtualHost=/");
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSignalR(route =>
    {
        route.MapHub<MyHub>("/mypath");
    });

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var bus = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IBus>();

        bus.SubscribeAsync<MyMessage>("MySubscription", async message =>
        {
            var hubContext = context.RequestServices
                .GetRequiredService<IHubContext<MyHub>>();

            // hubContext is null 
            await hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("MyNotification");
        });

        await next.Invoke();
    });
}
```

I suspect that perhaps I'm doing something wrong with regards to registering the subscription inside an `app.Use` but I can't seem to find any useful examples so this was the best I could figure.

I'm on ASP.NET Core 3 preview 5, I don't know if that has anything to do with my problem.

So the question is: how do I get the hub context inside the message subscription handler?

**UPDATE**

I've checked the [GetRequiredService docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceProviderServiceExtensions_GetRequiredService_System_IServiceProvider_System_Type_) and the call should actuall throw an `InvalidOperationException` if the service couldn't be resolved, but it doesn't. It returns `null`, which as far as I can tell, shouldn't be possible (unless the default container supports registration of null-valued instances).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue with help from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079509/asp-net-core-web-api-where-to-subscribe-rabbitmq) by implementing an `IHostedService` instead.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.RegisterEasyNetQ("host=localhost;virtualHost=/");
    services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSignalR(route =>
    {
        route.MapHub<MyHub>("/mypath");
    });    
}

public class MyHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public ServiceBusHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var bus = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBus>();

        bus.SubscribeAsync<MyMessage>("MySubscription", async message =>
        {
            var hubContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<MyHub>>();

            await hubContext.Clients
                .All
                .SendAsync("MyNotification", cancellationToken: stoppingToken);
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have a question, why we don't need to put the While loop or Timer Callback in ExecuteAsync for the bus.SubscribeAsync<>(); ? thank you in advance.

Comment: @Armin Shoeibi: since the service is registered as a hosted service, it will not need a loop to prevent the application from stopping. The bus message subscription is a callback that is issued by EasyNetQ.